# Python bot aiogram подключить хэндлеры

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

**Что должен уметь делать бот ?**

Команда /start >>> Бот запрашивает почту в юзера >>> принимает почту от юзера >>> задает следующий запрос, спрашивает что-то типо hash`a(чисто текст) >>> принимает ответ с хэшом от юзера >>> сохраняет информацию(переменную например) >>> появляется главное меню (тут уже можно не делать, это в будущем)

**Какие у меня проблемы на данный момент?**

Кажется я не зарегистрировал хэндлеры или команды. Очень прошу помочь с этим. Буду благодарен если Вы поможете мне доработать код, я лучше и быстрее смогу понять код.

**Мой код:** (Сейчас бот ничего не отвечает, просто молчит)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import logging
 
 
bot = Bot("TOKEN", parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
 
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
 
 
 
class GetUserInfo(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_user_mailbox = State()
    waiting_for_user_hash = State()
    
 
def register_handlers_food(dp: Dispatcher):
 
    dp.register_message_handler(get_user_mailbox, commands='start', state=GetUserInfo.waiting_for_user_mailbox)
    dp.register_message_handler(get_user_hash, state=GetUserInfo.waiting_for_user_hash)
 
 
async def get_user_mailbox(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Enter your mailbox address: ')
    await GetUserInfo.waiting_for_user_mailbox.set()
 
async def get_user_hash(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.lower() == 1:
        await message.answer('Okay')
    else:
        await message.answer('Else')
    await GetUserInfo.next()
    await message.answer('Now enter your hash code')
 
async def confirmation_info(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.lower() == 2 or 3:
        await message.answer('Two or Three')
    else:
        print('lol')
        await message.answer('Something Else')
 
    user_data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f'Your info: {user_data}')
    await state.finish()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # starting bot
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: оберните в декоратор с командой start

Comment: @verybadcoder , я оборачивал функцию get_user_mailbox декоратором (@dp.message_handler(commands="start")), дальше этой функции код не выходит. Спрашивает почту и уже не принимает ответ.

Comment: а почему не сделать получение ответа в той же функции?

Comment: @verybadcoder , пытался сделать по примеру (https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/quickstart/). Смогли бы Вы мне помочь и доработать код. Мне правда очень тяжело понять на словах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните первую функцию в декоратор с командой старт и установите внутри функции первое состояние:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def get_user_mailbox(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Enter your mailbox address: ')
    await GetUserInfo.waiting_for_user_mailbox.set()
```

Следующей функцией обработайте состояние, которое вы вызвали после команды старт:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=GetUserInfo.waiting_for_user_mailbox, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def mail_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Ваша почта: {message.text}')
```

Далее вы можете вызвать следующее состояние с помощью метода .set(), либо завершить состояние командой:

```
await state.finish()
```

Следующие состояния обрабатываются аналогично